# How can I restore a Heroku database detached?

Tags: heroku, database, upgrade, restore

I used to be a free plan Heroku user.
Since Heroku removed free plan my project databases have been detached (December 2022).
Heroku doesn't provide technical support for free applications.
As of today if I upgrade to a paid plan will have get the possibility to restore my databases?
If yes, which minimum plan (Eco, Basic, etc.) allow me to restore my databases?
Thank you